# Use an external debug print function in a library

Tags: c

I'm writing a library that I use with two different projects.
Both projects use a different architecture and some functions in the library are architecture dependent. For this case, I have a header mylib_arch.h defining these functions like this:

```
extern void mylib_func(void);
```

Then in project A and project B, I define these functions in a mylib_arch.c. So far so good, except for the logging function.

I actually would like to use a logging macro in my library and couldn't find a way to do that, so I added something like this instead:

```
extern void mylib_log(const char *fmt, ...);
```

Now in each project, I have a different way to display/print things but both use a macro so I couldn't define mylib_log using these macros.

My only way to solve this is to rewrite the log function using `vprintf` that takes a `va_list` so I can do something like this:

```
void mylib_log(const char *fmt, ...)
{
     va_list args;

     va_start(args, fmt);
     vprintf(fmt, args);
     va_end(args);
}
```

This is not ideal because I'd like this function to have a similar output than my `LOG_DEBUG(fmt, ...)` macro
So this can work but I'm wondering if there is another way?

Comment: If you want something similar to another thing, then it could be helpful to show us the other thing. What output do you get now? What output do you want to get? Perhaps you could create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that's not the problem, I could reproduce the same output. I just don't like code duplication.

Comment: @alk I did, basically I'd like to be able to use my logging macro in a library that is agnostic to the implementation

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, I think what you want to do is this.
First, keep your function

```
extern void mylib_log(const char *fmt, ...);
```

Then, add a second function

```
extern void mylib_vlog(const char *fmt, va_list);
```

The `mylib_log` function is architecture-agnostic.  You'll have two completely independent implementations of `mylib_vlog`, one for each architecture.  Finally, `mylib_log` is written in terms of `mylib_vlog`, in the obvious way.  You don't even need any macros or ifdefs.

Comment: Actually it seems I didn't explain it clearly looking at the downvotes
But in both project there are logging macros that I'd like to re-use, for ex:
`LOG_DEBUG(TAG, "hello %d", 42);`

I guess that's not possible because of the ##VA_ARGS

Comment: @Ervadac Where I work, we've got a logging macro exactly like that, so it can be made to work, but it's a bit tricky, especially if you want it to work under older compilers that don't have variadic macros.